# Integration of following trigonometry

Tags: integration

please help me obtain the integral of the following trigonometric equation:- 1/((a*sin(x))^2 + (b*cos(x))^2)^2)

I have tried taking cos x term out and putting tan x equal to t, but have failed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: is it $$\int \frac{1}{((a\sin(x))^2+(b\cos(x))^2)^2}dx$$?